# Can't set var in subview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an app with a UIViewController with custom UIViews in it. I want to set a variable in that custom UIView and it doesn't update...
I have done this a thousand times and it always worked but this time it doesn't and I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help is welcome!

In my viewcontroller:

```
var sjablonview: sjablonPicker!
sjablonview = sjablonPicker(frame: CGRect(x: btnUndo.frame.origin.x, y: DrawingView.frame.origin.y,
                                              width: (btnX.frame.origin.x + btnX.frame.size.width) - btnUndo.frame.origin.x, height: 250))
sjablonview.alpha = 1
sjablonview.mpUitklapping = 300
self.view.addSubview(sjablonview)
```

In my custom UIView:

```
class sjablonPicker: UIView {

var mpUitklapping = CGFloat(100)

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    print(mpUitklapping) // --> output = 100 and not 300
...
```

Comment: The print statement in the `init` is called long before you are able to set the `mpUitklapping` property.

Comment: Put a `print` where you do `sjablonview.mpUitklapping = 300` and see which happens first.

Comment: FYI - Class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I was really dumb, sorry haha ! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing from inside your initialiser. Your view is initialized **before** you change the value of `mpUitklapping`. Your initializer gets called from this line:

```
sjablonview = sjablonPicker(frame: CGRect(x: btnUndo.frame.origin.x, y: DrawingView.frame.origin.y, width: (btnX.frame.origin.x + btnX.frame.size.width) - btnUndo.frame.origin.x, height: 250))
```

The value gets changed, you just don't print the updated value.